# Følner sequences of the integers

Tags: gr.group-theory, measure-theory, amenability

**Definition:** Let $G$ be a group. For $g\in G$ and a subset $F\subseteq G$ fix
the notation $gF:=\{gf\mid f\in G\}$. A sequence $(F_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq G$
is called a *Følner sequence* if
\begin{eqnarray}
\nonumber
\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\#(gF_{i}\triangle F_{i})}{\#F_{i}}=0
\end{eqnarray}
for every $g\in G$. Here $gF_{i}\triangle F_{i}:=(gF_{i}\cup F_{i})\setminus(gF_{i}\cap F_{i})$
denotes the *symmetric difference* of $gF_{i}$ and $F_{i}$.

**Question:** Consider the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and define $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$
via $f(x):=\sqrt{|x|}$. Can we find a Følner sequence $(F_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$
such that the following holds:
\begin{eqnarray}
\nonumber
\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{k \in F_i} [f(k)-f(k-1)]}{\#F_{i}}>0\:?
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Do you require that this limit exists? or do you just want limsup or liminf to be positive?

Comment: The positivity of the limsup or liminf would already suffice. But as I understand from Sean's answer this can not happen, right?

Comment: Yes, the answer proves that the limit is zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. We have an estimate of the form $|f(k) - f(k-1)| \le C / \sqrt{|k|+1}$. Therefore $|f(k) - f(k-1)| \le \epsilon$ except at $O(\epsilon^{-2})$ values, so $\sum_{k \in F_i} |f(k) - f(k-1)| / |F_i| \le O(\epsilon) + O(\epsilon^{-2} / |F_i|)$. Putting $\epsilon = 1/|F_i|^{1/3}$, we get $\sum_{k \in F_i} |f(k) - f(k-1)| / |F_i| \le O(1/|F_i|^{1/3})$. Note the Følner property is not required.

Comment: More precisely the Følner property is only used to ensure that $|F_i|\to\infty$. Actually the sum is bounded by the same sum taken over $[-|F|/2,|F|/2]$, so is indeed in $O(1/|F|^{1/2})$.